# Energy of anihilation in the form of heat

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose you have a closed system. Within it is 2 protons, an anti-proton, 2 electrons, and a positron. All particles are barely above absolute zero in temperature.

A proton collides with the anti-proton, an electron collides with a positron, and all are annihilated.

All of the energy of this annihilation transfers to the remaining proton and electron in the form of heat.

How hot would the "hydrogen plasma" or whatever you call the remaining particles be?

Answer (score 1):

> A proton collides with the anti-proton, an electron collides with a positron, and all are annihilated.

[In this bubble chamber](http://www.particleadventure.org/all_decay.html) picture an antiproton hits a proton:

[image: bubbleC antiproton annihilation]

> All of the energy of this annihilation transfers to the remaining proton and electron in the form of heat.

You can see the charged products running away transferring very little in ionization energy on the medium ( liquid hydrogen), They hit the walls. There are a number of gammas coming from the unseen [pi0 decays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion). They also escape without even an ionization trace.

If they were in vacuum , they would lose no energy before hitting the walls of the container . The probability of ever meeting each other is zero because they come from an explosion point. The electron will be left hanging , if it is vacuum, and will have a very small probability of meeting the proton sometime and make a hydrogen atom.

> How hot would the "hydrogen plasma" or whatever you call the remaining particles be?

There is thus **nothing left** in the container and the walls will be heated a bit or turn slightly radioactive depending on the interactions of the pions and gammas with the wall.

The words *hot* and *plasma*  are attributes of statistical collections of matter studied by thermodynamics and cannot be applied to small numbers. Matter consists of about 10^23 molecules per mole on which temperature and other emergent properties can be assigned.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. A larger sample can be used. Measure the energy in calories, then figure by the coefficient of heat, to get the average temperature of the remaining particles.Or forget annihilation and simply convert the energy of the particles and calculate the average temp of the particles absorbing all their energy in the form of heat..don't worry about HOW particles annihilate, this is a theoretical not to be duplicated in a lab.

Comment: I am sorry but you cannot have a theoretical temperature with zero particles in the box. They disappear as soon as they annihilate so even if you take the temperature as an average from kinetic energy of the two remaining particles you are close to 0. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory#Temperature_and_kinetic_energy

Comment: 1 There are not zero particles in the box.2 matter,energy can not be destroyed

Comment: @Michael the energy ends up at the walls in nanoseconds, as the "explosion" products hit it. Of course energy is conserved, at the walls of the container. They do not interact between themselves to define a uniform medium that can be assigned a temperature

Comment: protons have the energy 938.257 MeV. = 3.590458832911E-20 kcal 

the electron has the energy -13.6eV. = -5.2043566024649E-22 kcal

Comment: sure they do, it is absorbed by the interaction of the pions and photons etc with the walls, though part of it leaves with the neutrinos muons of charged pion decays. Energy is not vague, it is carried by particles from photons to protons to .... . To establish a temperature these particles have to interact with each other and create a stable thermodynamic ensemble.

Comment: Both particles have a rest energy of 0.511 mega electron volts (MeV). When the mass of the two particles is converted entirely into energy, this rest energy is what is given off. The energy is given off in the form of the aforementioned gamma rays. Each of the gamma rays has an energy of 0.511 MeV.The theoretical is the universe which has no walls.the particles, photons, and energy in gamma rays of the theorized matter/antimatter annihilations must be accounted for if CP violation is true.

Comment: i don't believe that CP violation is in agreement with observational data and proven science. Even NASA and WIKI says so. i believe antimatter is half of the universe even though it is a mystery to standard theory, and not predicted by big bang theory.

Comment: That is another story/question